# Alternating players

Tags: c++

I am trying to realize a game and I want to play my two players turn.
here is the code

```
class Game {
private:
    Grid gameboard;
    Player *players[2];
public:
    Game(int len, string ps1, string ps2);
    void gamePlay();
};
```

`Player` is the `class abstract`.  `Angel` and `Devil` inherited to `Player`
And here my implementation
My Constructor:

```
Game::Game(int len, string ps1, string ps2){
    gameBoard.setLen(len);
    players[0] = new Angel(ps1, gameBoard.getLen()/2, gameBoard.getLen()/2, gameBoard);
    players[1] = new Devil(ps2);
}
```

and in there I want to rotate the players each round

```
void Game::gamePlay(){
    int count;
    do{
        gameBoard.display();
        cout << "It 's" << players[0]->getName() << " to play" << endl;
        players[0]->play(gameBoard);
        gameBoard.display();
        cout << "It's" << joueurs[1]->getName() << " to play !" << endl;
        players[1]->play(gameBoard);
        count++;
    }while(count != 10); /* It 's just for test */
}
```

how do I do that?

Thank's you

Comment: What do you mean by 'rotate' players? Switch turns?

Comment: that is to say to each loop is another player who needs to play
It's a game of two style player a Tic Tac Toe

Comment: yes but I was wondering if I can do something like this:

player =  (player% 2) + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you 0 and 1 consecutively:

say `int counter = 0;`

```
if(counter % 2 == 0)
{
// player O
}else
{
// player X
}

counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
player = (player + 1) & 1
```

This will alternate between 0 and 1.

This will also do it:

```
player = (player + 1) % 2
```

Comment: and `player = 1-player;`

Comment: To make it more general, perhaps one should user the number of elements in `players`, if one then increases the number of players, it will still work.